# Get url of enbedded flash video on iPad

Tags: ipad, video, adobe-flash

Before you jump on me I know flash is not supported on the iPad. I just want to know how I can get the url (if possible) of these embedded videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the app, but [WebInspector](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/web-inspector-premium/id421392979?mt=8) looks like it will show you the source. You might find that the servers are sniffing the user agents, and they don't even send you the link, but you can try the free version (ad supported) before spending any money on the app to be sure it does what you wish.